# Restler always returning error 404 not found

Tags: php, rest, http-status-code-404, restler

I can't seem to figure this one out.

The class:

```
class Assets {
 function getOne($id) {
    $asset = DBO_Asset::getOneByPublicId($id);

    return $asset->id;
 }
}
```

The index.php:

```
require_once 'restler/restler.php';
require_once 'API/Assets.php';

$rest = new Restler();
$rest->addAPIClass("Assets");
$rest->handle();
```

The URL:

```
http://localhost/api/index.php/assets/getOne/8TWVTZAU
```

The result:

```
{
  "error": {
  "code": 404,
  "message": "Not Found"
  }
}
```

I have no idea why this is creating a 404, but I followed the instructions, and I am still not getting anywhere. Can someone please help me figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restler is using `get`, `post`, `put`, `delete` as method prefixes to automatically map them to respective HTTP method/verb

GET is the default HTTP method, so if you dont prefix a method with any of the above, it will be mapped to GET method

Your api is currently mapping to the following url

`http://localhost/api/index.php/assets/one/8TWVTZAU`

If having `getOne` in the url is important for you, use `@url` comment as shown below to manually route that way

```
class Assets
{
    /**
     * @url GET getOne/:id
     * @url GET getOne
     */
    function getOne($id)
    {
        $asset = DBO_Asset::getOneByPublicId($id);
        return $asset->id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that clarified a whole lot! =)