# how to POST data using Curl in php?

Tags: php, web-services, curl, restler

I have created webservices in restler framework and I am trying to insert data using curl in php from client lib that I have created.

`api.php`

```
/**
     * Manually routed method. we can specify as many routes as we want
     *
     * @url POST addcomment/{token}/{email}/{comment}/{story_id}
     */
    function addComment($token,$email,$comment,$story_id){
        return $this->dp->insertComment($token,$email,$comment,$story_id);
    }
```

for testing purpose from client : `testing.php`

```
$data_string = "token=900150983cd24fb0d6963f7d28e17f72&email=kamal@gmail.com&comment=commentusingcurl&story_id=2";                                                                                   

$ch = curl_init('http://localhost/Restler/public/examples/news/addcomment');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array("Content-Type : text","Content-lenght:".strlen($data_string)));                                                                                                                                     
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

but it's throwing **404**. Please help.

Comment: may be it is not getting the url path.

Comment: i am getting sucess using GET method.

Comment: Well, 404 is just a not found response. Have you checked that the URL is correct? Try it in a browser or from the command line.

Comment: So use `GET` if it is working.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be mapping all the parameters to URL,

```
/**
 * Manually routed method. we can specify as many routes as we want
 *
 * @url POST addcomment/{token}/{email}/{comment}/{story_id}
 */
function addComment($token,$email,$comment,$story_id){
    return $this->dp->insertComment($token,$email,$comment,$story_id);
}
```

By doing so the API can only accept URL such as

```
http://localhost/Restler/public/examples/news/addcomment/900150983cd24fb0d6963f7d28e17f72/kamal@gmail.com/commentusingcurl/2
```

Change you API method to

```
/**
 * Manually routed method. we can specify as many routes as we want
 *
 * @url POST addcomment
 */
function addComment($token,$email,$comment,$story_id){
    return $this->dp->insertComment($token,$email,$comment,$story_id);
}
```

Then your cURL example should work fine

```
$data_string = "token=900150983cd24fb0d6963f7d28e17f72&email=kamal@gmail.com&comment=commentusingcurl&story_id=2";

$ch = curl_init('http://localhost/Restler/public/examples/news/addcomment');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array("Content-Type : text","Content-lenght:".strlen($data_string)));                                                                                                                                     
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: hy thanx to confirm the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

```
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array("Content-Type : text","Content-lenght:".strlen($data_string)));
```

**NOTE:** Uncomment the line may be.

See the example of post data using curl.

```
function post($requestJson) {

        $postUrl = $this->endpoint."?access_token=".$this->token;

        //Get length of post
        $postlength = strlen($requestJson);

        //open connection
        $ch = curl_init();

        //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$postUrl);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,$postlength);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$requestJson);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        //close connection
        curl_close($ch);

        return $response;
    }
```

Checkout some links for more information,

[Execute a HTTP POST Using PHP CURL](http://davidwalsh.name/curl-post)

[Submitting a form post with PHP and CURL](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-curl-form-post/)

[Post to a URL Using cURL and PHP](http://bavotasan.com/2011/post-url-using-curl-php/)

[Setup a simple cURL connection to POST data using PHP](http://digipiph.com/blog/setup-simple-curl-connection-post-data-using-php)

**Edit:**

[Restler always returning error 404 not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12046207/restler-always-returning-error-404-not-found)

may help you.

Comment: did u ever define POST param in restler ?I hv doubt I may not correct.

Comment: @ketulshah checkout my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10506060/facebook-curl-posting-as-me/10514420#10514420

Comment: @ketulshah i never used restler framework but that's not the issue.

Comment: @ketulshah u have updated version in restler framework? & check my answer after edit one link.

Comment: yeah  i m using v 3 of restler

Comment: oh i got....i just changed the @url in comment `/**
     
     * @url POST addcomment/
     */`

Comment: your answer may be correct but it doesn't relate to my questions. I would like to thank for your efforts. If i will accept your Answer it will misguide the people who are looking for relevant answer.

Comment: i dn't have enough reputation sry :(