# How to put the value of a submitted form in a string?

Tags: php, string, forms, post

I've got two files. Let's call them a.php and b.php. In a.php, I want to show the result of b.php, when post data is submitted to this b.php.
If it's not totally clear yet, here's what the files kind of look like.
a.php:

```
$one = "apple";
$two = "pear";
$three = "phone";

$array = array(
        "one" => $one,
        "two" => $two,
        "three" => $three
);

$string = postformdataintoafile($array, "b.php");
```

Obviously, `postformdataintoafile(`) is not a real function, but I hope you get the idea. So, what I would like to know is how this is going to work and with what functions I should do it.

And `$string` should actually be the whole HTML-page, that is created.

If anyone could help me with this, it would be very appreciated.

Comment: _I hope you get the idea_... Actually, no.

Comment: Maybe simulate the form submit with a curl request to b.php?

Comment: Could I put it in a string with curl?

Comment: Alternative to what @ManiacTwister is suggesting could be a javascript ajax request. Both would work, not sure what would be easier/more suitable for you.

Comment: If b.php is creating the html page what is the role of a.php? Couldn't they be joint? A dirty solution would be to use `include('b.php')` and the already set variables can be seen by the included file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14892309/how-to-post-data-using-curl-in-php

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic AJAX situation.

The file `b.php` is what we call the AJAX processor.

Use js/jQuery to collect the field values, and then an AJAX construct to submit them to `b.php`.

After processing, `b.php` uses the PHP `echo` command to return the results to `a.php`, where they appear in the `success` function of the AJAX routine.

Here is a post that gives some simple examples:

[AJAX request callback using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973386/ajax-request-callback-using-jquery/17974843#17974843)